# ffmpeg creating small black bar on down scaled videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I am running ffmpeg on a folder of videos all with various resolutions and I am down scaling them to 25% size. But all of my outputs have a tiny black border on one side.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxbIC.png

Here is an example of what I mean, left is the original video and right is the output.
The scaling is working fine, although it seems to be swapping w/h but the file still plays back in the correct orientation.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nszeg.png

here are my params:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "$f" -filter:v "scale=iw/4:ih/4" -c:v hevc_amf -c:a copy "../${f%.*}.mp4"
```

I am using ffmpeg version git-2020-08-02-b48397e. I need these to actually resize without a random black bar. I have tried every configuration of the scale parameter among other things and I always get the same result.

here is an example log:

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-08-02-b48397e Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.1 (GCC) 20200726
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --enable-librav1e --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 57.100 / 56. 57.100
  libavcodec     58. 99.100 / 58. 99.100
  libavformat    58. 49.100 / 58. 49.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
  libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'BONK6556.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2020-01-18T22:26:45.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:11.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15014 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 14919 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2020-01-18T22:26:45.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 92 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-18T22:26:45.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
File '../BONK6556.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> hevc (hevc_amf))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp4, to '../BONK6556.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    encoder         : Lavf58.49.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (hevc_amf) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p, 270x480, q=2-31, 2000 kb/s, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.99.100 hevc_amf
      creation_time   : 2020-01-18T22:26:45.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 92 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-18T22:26:45.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
frame=  183 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:07.57 bitrate=1661.1kbits/s speed=15.1x   frame=  332 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=    2819kB time=00:00:11.03 bitrate=2092.7kbits/s speed=13.1x  
video:2685kB audio:123kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.373649%
```

Comment: Show the **complete** log from your command.

Comment: @llogan ok added.